# parent.iframePDF is undefined

Tags: javascript

I get 'parent.iframePDF is undefined' JavaScript error when i use the below code in Firefox and an 'object expected' error in IE.

Can someone tell me what it is that i'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
function PrintFrame(xFile){
    parent.iframePDF.location.href = xFile;
    document.getElementById("spanMess").style.display = "block";

    parent.iframePDF.onload = new function() {
        setTimeout("parent.iframePDF.print();parent.document.getElementById('spanMess').style.display='none';",10000);
    }
}

<iframe id="iframePDF" src="about:blank" style="display:none"></iframe>

<input type="image" onclick="PrintFrame('525.pdf')" src="../../cms_res/DisneyChannel/playhouse/images/buttons/printer.png" />

<span id="spanMess" style="display:none;color:red;">
    <h3>Preparing Document For Print</h3>
</span>
```

Comment: `iframePDF` is not in `parent`, is it?

Comment: Why are you using parent? I suspect `document.getElementById("iframePDF")` might work better here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use name="iframePDF" instead of id="iframePDF".
In that way, you can use window.iframePDF (-> window.frames.iframePDF).

If you use document.getElementById('iframePDF'), then you can't use .location.href on that.

Edit: Tim is right, no parent is needed here.

Comment: Thanks! I've got a wierdness with firefox in that it doesn't print but i think that's just firefox!

Comment: You don't need `parent`. It's incorrect and only works by coincidence. Use `window` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code may not work for succeeding calls of PrintFrame on other browsers, the problem is that the onload event on iframe may not fire anymore.

You may try this:

```
function frameLoaded(frame){
   frame.contentWindow.print();
   document.getElementById('spanMess').style.display='none';",10000);
}

function PrintFrame(xFile){
   var holder = document.getElementById('iframePDFHolder');
   holder.innerHTML = '<iframe onload="frameLoaded(this)" src=" + xFile + '"></iframe>';
}

<div id="iframePDFHolder" style="display:none;"></div>

<input type="image" onclick="PrintFrame('525.pdf')" src="../../cms_res/DisneyChannel/playhouse/images/buttons/printer.png" />
<span id="spanMess" style="display:none;color:red;"><h3>Preparing Document For Print</h3></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that `parent` refers to the window object of the document containing the current document and you actually want to call a function in the current document, so the `parent` is not required.

Second, you should use `document.getElementById("iframePDF")` rather than relying on IE's nasty featrue of creating properties of the global object corresponding to IDs of elements in the page. To get the iframe's window object you can use the (non-standard but widely supported) `contentWindow` property. Alternatively, assign a `name` to your iframe instead of an id and use `window.frames["iframePDF"]`.

Third, `new function() {...}` is not what you want: the `new` there is not necessary and confusing; drop that.

Fourth, assigning an `onload` property to an iframe object will not work in all browsers. You need to handle the `load` event within the document loaded into the iframe and call a function in the main document, using `parent` to get hold of the containing document.

Comment: "First problem is that parent refers to the window object of the document containing the current document"  This line just saved me so much time. Thanks.